# ie10 html5 audio preload

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, html5-audio

I've been working on a musician's site with html5 audio playback.  Everything works fine in Firefox and Chrome, but IE has been giving me issues, and I narrowed it down to the way I'm loading the media.

Part of my strategy to obfuscate the media source is to have an audio tag with no source, then add the source via javascript.

If I manually write the html, IE10 honors the preload="none" attribute, but if I don't include the sources and add them to the DOM via javascript, the preload attribute is ignored.

Example 1 works as intended:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 audio test</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>
This is an audio tag with two source tag children of different types.  Preload is set to none.
</p>

<audio id="audiotest" preload="none" controls>
  <source src="test.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="test.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Example 2 loads starts to download the media despite the preload attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5 audio test</title>
</head>
<body>

<p>
This is just an audio tag with preload none with javascript adding the sources.
</p>

<audio id="audiotest" preload="none" controls>
</audio>

<script>
var oggSource = document.createElement('source');
oggSource.type='audio/ogg';
oggSource.src='test.ogg';

var mp3Source = document.createElement('source');
mp3Source.type='audio/mpeg';
mp3Source.src='test.mp3';

document.getElementById("audiotest").appendChild(oggSource);
document.getElementById("audiotest").appendChild(mp3Source);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here are the working examples:

http://www.joshblackburn.com/test1.php
http://www.joshblackburn.com/test2.php

I was trying to figure out why none of my controls were working in IE.  I figured out that it was downloading every single track and locking things up.  Using the dev panel in IE10, the network trace confirms the issue.

Is this an IE bug?  Do I need to figure out different ways of obfuscating my sources?

The 'real' page is www.joshblackburn.com/new.php?page=albums if anyone is interested.

Comment: Why are you bothering with simple and hackish obfuscation? Anybody with a modern browser can open a dev console and see the sources of all media elements, regardless of how the source attribute is set. I recommend you save yourself a few vain headaches and go with the simplest straight forward approach.

Comment: Codemonkey, the average user has no idea what a dev console is, let alone how to use it.  Simple obfuscation like this will prevent average users and bots from acquiring the media sources directly.

Comment: The average user doesn't know how to search for media sources in HTML either. I can half-way understand your concern about bots though.